# R subset unique observation keeping last entry

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks something like this (with a lot more observations)

```
df <- structure(list(session_user_id = c("1803f6c3625c397afb4619804861f75268dfc567", 
"1924cb2ebdf29f052187b9a2d21673e4d314199b", "1924cb2ebdf29f052187b9a2d21673e4d314199b", 
"1924cb2ebdf29f052187b9a2d21673e4d314199b", "1924cb2ebdf29f052187b9a2d21673e4d314199b", 
"198b83b365fef0ed637576fe1bde786fc09817b2", "19fd8069c094fb0697508cc9646513596bea30c4", 
"19fd8069c094fb0697508cc9646513596bea30c4", "19fd8069c094fb0697508cc9646513596bea30c4", 
"19fd8069c094fb0697508cc9646513596bea30c4", "1a3d33c9cbb2aa41515e6ef76f123b2ea8ee2f13", 
"1b64c142b1540c43e3f813ccec09cb2dd7907c14", "1b7346d13f714c97725ba2e1c21b600535164291"
), raw_score = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.2, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.2, 1), 
    submission_time = c(1389707078L, 1389694184L, 1389694188L, 
    1389694189L, 1389694194L, 1390115495L, 1389696939L, 1389696971L, 
    1389741306L, 1389985033L, 1389983862L, 1389854836L, 1389692240L
    )), .Names = c("session_user_id", "raw_score", "submission_time"
), row.names = 28:40, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a new data frame with only one observation per "session_ user_id" by keeping the one with the latest "submission_time."

The only idea that I have in mind is to create a list of unique users. Write a loop to find the max of submission_time for each user and then write a loop that gets raw score fore that user and time.

Can somebody show me a better way of doing this in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could first order your `data.frame` by `submission_time` and remove all duplicated `session_user_id` entries afterwards:

```
## order by submission_time
df <- df[order(df$submission_time, decreasing=TRUE),]

## remove duplicated user_id
df <- df[!duplicated(df$session_user_id),]

#                            session_user_id raw_score submission_time
#33 198b83b365fef0ed637576fe1bde786fc09817b2       0.2      1390115495
#37 19fd8069c094fb0697508cc9646513596bea30c4       1.0      1389985033
#38 1a3d33c9cbb2aa41515e6ef76f123b2ea8ee2f13       1.0      1389983862
#39 1b64c142b1540c43e3f813ccec09cb2dd7907c14       0.2      1389854836
#28 1803f6c3625c397afb4619804861f75268dfc567       1.0      1389707078
#32 1924cb2ebdf29f052187b9a2d21673e4d314199b       1.0      1389694194
#40 1b7346d13f714c97725ba2e1c21b600535164291       1.0      1389692240
```

Answer (score 11):

This is simple to express with dplyr: first group by session id, then filter, selecting the row in each group with the maximum time:

```
library(dplyr)
df %.%
  group_by(session_user_id) %.%
  filter(submission_time == max(submission_time))
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to keep all maximum times (if duplicated), you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %.%
  group_by(session_user_id) %.%
  filter(row_number(desc(submission_time)) == 1)
```

Comment: The second one picks out the earliest time, since the raw data is sorted in increasing chronological order

Comment: @James oops, fixed. But the order of the raw data won't affect either operation.

Answer (score 4):

I'll add a `data.table` solution as well, and out of curiosity benchmark against `dplyr` on bigger data:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[DT[, .I[which.max(submission_time)], by=list(session_user_id)]$V1]
```

Here I'm assuming that the OP needs just *one* observation, even for multiple identical "max" values. If not, check out the function `f2` below.

---

#### Benchmarks on bigger data vs `dplyr`:

Benchmark against @hadley's `dplyr` solutions on bigger data. I'll assume there are about 50e3 user ids and there are a total of 1e7 rows.

```
require(data.table)  # 1.8.11 commit 1142
require(dplyr)       # latest commit from github
set.seed(45L)
DT <- data.table(session_user_id = sample(paste0("id", 1:5e4), 1e7, TRUE), 
                 raw_score = sample(10, 1e7, TRUE), 
                 submission_time = sample(1e5:5e5, 1e7, TRUE))

DF <- tbl_df(as.data.frame(DT))

f1 <- function(DT) {
    DT[DT[, .I[which.max(submission_time)], by=list(session_user_id)]$V1]
}

f2 <- function(DT) {
    DT[DT[, .I[submission_time == max(submission_time)], 
            by=list(session_user_id)]$V1]
}

f3 <- function(DF) {
    DF %.%
        group_by(session_user_id) %.%
        filter(submission_time == max(submission_time))
}

f4 <- function(DF) {
    DF %.%
      group_by(session_user_id) %.%
      filter(row_number(desc(submission_time)) == 1)
}
```

And here are the timings. All are minimum of three runs:

```
system.time(a1 <- f1(DT)) 
#   user  system elapsed
#  1.044   0.056   1.101

system.time(a2 <- f2(DT)) 
#   user  system elapsed
#  1.384   0.080   1.475

system.time(a3 <- f3(DF)) 
#   user  system elapsed
#  4.513   0.044   4.555

system.time(a4 <- f4(DF)) 
#   user  system elapsed
#  6.312   0.004   6.314
```

As expected `f4` is the slowest because it uses `desc` (which I'm guessing somehow involves in an ordering or sorting *per group* - a more computationally expensive operation than just getting `max` or `which.max`).

Here, `a1` and `a4` (only one observation even if multiple max values are present) give identical results and so does `a2` and `a3` (all max values).

`data.table` is at least 3x faster here (comparing `a2` to `a3`) and about 5.7x times faster when comparing `f1` to `f4`.

Comment: I get better timings for the `dplyr` functions (1.8, and 2.6 for f3 and f4) but I'm also using the CRAN version, same for data.table (which I'm getting slightly slower times from). What's your rig like? I'm running a i7-3930k.

Comment: It's hard to compare 1.8 and 2.6 without data.table timings (from 1.8.11 commit 1142). I'm guessing the 1.101 and 1.475 will also be much faster on yours. So, it evens out.

Comment: It was the opposite actually. That's why I was wondering what kind of machine you have.

Comment: I've tested it on a mac with 10.9 and on a linux machine (Debian Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 x86_64). Which version of data.table are you using?

Comment: As I mentioned, there are quite a few (silly) bugs during aggregation that were fixed recently. So, it's imperative to check the timings on 1.8.11 commit >= 1142.

Comment: Allright, will do. Still in the learning phase for data.table. Haven't quite wrapped my head around it yet.

Comment: Brandon, no problem. Glad to help. If you've any questions, feel free to post it on SO or the data.table mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the "plyr' package to summarize the data. Something like this should work

```
max_subs<-ddply(df,"session_user_id",summarize,max_sub=max(submission_time))
```

ddply takes a data frame in and returns a data frame, and this will give you the user and submission times you want.

To return the original data frame rows corresponding to these you could do

```
df2<-df[df$session_user_id %in% max_subs$session_user_id & df$submission_time %in% max_subs$max_sub,]
```

Comment: I wonder how fast this would be in comparison to a typical sort and dedup like sgibbs answer.

Answer (score 2):

First find the max submission time by session_user_id. This table will be unique by session_user_id.

Then just merge (sql-speak: inner join) back to your original table joining on submission_time & session_user_id (R automatically picks up common names across the two data frames).

```
maxSessions<-aggregate(submission_time~session_user_id , df, max)
mySubset<-merge(df, maxSessions)
mySubset #this table has the data your are looking for
```

If you are looking for speed and your dataset is large then have a look at this [How to summarize data by group in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/how-to-summarize-data-by-group-in-r) `data.table` & `plyr` are good choices.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extended comment because I was interested in how fast each of the solutions were

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <- df[sample(1:nrow(df),10000,replace=TRUE),] # 10k records

fun.test1 <- function(df) {
  df <- df[order(df$submission_time, decreasing = TRUE),]
  df <- df[!duplicated(df$session_user_id),]
  return(df)
}

fun.test2 <- function(df) { 
  max_subs<-ddply(df,"session_user_id",summarize,max_sub=max(submission_time))
  df2<-df[df$session_user_id %in% max_subs$session_user_id & 
          df$submission_time %in% max_subs$max_sub,]
  return(df2)
}

fun.test3 <- function(df) {
  df <- df %.%
    group_by(session_user_id) %.%
    filter(submission_time == max(submission_time))
  return(df)
}

fun.test4 <- function(df) {
  maxSessions<-aggregate(submission_time~session_user_id , df, max)
  mySubset<-merge(df, maxSessions)
  return(mySubset)
}

fun.test5 <- function(df) { 
  df <- df[df$submission_time %in% by(df, df$session_user_id,
           function(x) max(x$submission_time)),]
  return(df)
}

dt <- as.data.table(df) # Assuming you're working with data.table to begin with
# Don't know a lot about data.table so I'm sure there's a faster solution
fun.test6 <- function(dt) { 
  dt <- unique(
    dt[,
       list(raw_score,submission_time=max(submission_time)),
       by=session_user_id]
    )
  return(dt)
}
```

Looks like the most basic solution with `!duplicated()` wins by a significant margin for small data (Under 1k), followed by `dplyr`. `dplyr` wins for large samples (over 1k).

```
microbenchmark(
 fun.test1(df),
 fun.test2(df),
 fun.test3(df),
 fun.test4(df),
 fun.test5(df),
 fun.test6(dt)
)

         expr        min          lq     median         uq        max neval
 fun.test1(df)   2476.712   2660.0805   2740.083   2832.588   9162.339   100
 fun.test2(df)   5847.393   6215.1420   6335.932   6477.745  12499.775   100
 fun.test3(df)    815.886    924.1405   1003.585   1050.169   1128.915   100
 fun.test4(df) 161822.674 167238.5165 172712.746 173254.052 225317.480   100
 fun.test5(df)   5611.329   5899.8085   6000.555   6120.123  57572.615   100
 fun.test6(dt) 511481.105 541534.7175 553155.852 578643.172 627739.674   100
```

Comment: Is there a `data.table` solution here or you just loaded it out of habit ;)? And please, bigger data :).

Comment: haha, fun.test6 was "my" data.table solution, but as I commented, I'm sure there's a faster way to do it.

Comment: Oh damn, I dint think of scrolling down.. sorry about that. Will check.

Comment: Reran with 10k records, for sure there's a faster way with data.table, enlighten me Arun.

Comment: Brandon, I've added an answer and benchmarks with `dplyr`. You may run that code and recheck the timings (but it has to be >=1142 commit from 1.8.11, quite a few bug fixes and optimisations there).